# I try to create a sql request

Tags: sql

Given the following model (entities with keys) :

- Entity A : field1 field2
- Entity B : field1 field2 field3
- Entity C : field1 field3

I'm trying to make a SQL request giving me all the "field2" fields (of the A entity) for which the B entity is associated with C entities where the "field3" field has the value = 'val'

Can you help me ?

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: This is so abstract it hurts...

Answer (score 0):

Kind of painful to assist when you dont list the database version or give a SQLFiddle but here is a quick attempt.

```
SELECT A.Field2
FROM EntityA as A
INNER JOIN EntityB as B
ON A.Field2 = B.Field2
INNER JOIN
EntityC as C
ON C.Field1 = B.Field1
WHERE C.Field3 is null
```

This is without knowing the relationship between the tables also...so its a complete guess because I have no way of knowing what is truly foreign keys and what is not.